# Core Data Child Context Fails to Push Changes to Parent Context

Tags: swift, core-data

My app retrieves some JSON. I make a dispatch call, retrieve the main queue and insert the JSON data into Core Data using the parent/main object context.

The retrieved JSON also includes an image address. I send it's retrieval to the background queue and there requires a child managed object context as the parent is not retained. The code below outlines my image retrieval.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: json["KategoriResim"].stringValue) else { return }

    let privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateManagedObjectContext.parentContext = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
      guard let httpUrlResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpUrlResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data where error == nil
        else {
          print("Problem downloading the image of the category with id: \(category.id) and name: \(category.title)")
          return
      }

      if let privateCategory = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: privateManagedObjectContext) as? Category {
        privateCategory.logo = data
      }

      if privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
          try privateManagedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
          print("An error occured while saving the child context: \(error)")
        }
      }
    }.resume()
}
```

Even though the saves of the child managed object context are successful or there aren't any other error messages, the child context does not get pushed into the parent.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

My modification after Martin R's comment:

```
let privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateManagedObjectContext.parentContext = CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext

CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: json["KategoriResim"].stringValue) else { return }

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let httpUrlResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpUrlResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data where error == nil
            else {
                print("Problem downloading the image of the category with id: \(category.id) and name: \(category.title)")
                return
        }

        if let privateCategory = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: privateManagedObjectContext) as? Category {
            privateCategory.logo = data
        }
    }.resume()
}

if privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges {
    do {
        try privateManagedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("An error occured while saving the child context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not create your own dispatch queues for Core Data operations. Use the perform/performAndWait methods of the managed object context instead.

Comment: @MartinR I removed the background dispatch call and moved whatever inside it to `CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.performBlock{...}`. Although it still doesn't perform as I expected. The image retrieved still gets it's own insertion and not tied to the insertions made by the parent managed object context.

Comment: Please take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809670/swift-3-parent-child-context-crash-core-data-libcabi-dylib-terminating-wit?rq=1